# delta method question

Tags: statistics, asymptotics

Let $H:\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^k$ be measurable and differentiable at $x_0$, i.e. $$H(x) = H(x_0) + L(x-x_0) + o(x-x_0)$$ near $x_0$.

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ and $X$ are random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $\sqrt{n}(X_n-x_0)\Rightarrow X$. Show that $$\sqrt{n}[H(x)-H(x_0)] \Rightarrow L(X).$$

---

My question is this. When you multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n}$, yes you have $$\sqrt{n}[H(X_n)-H(x_0)] = L\sqrt{n}(X_n-x_0) + \sqrt{n} [o(X_n - x_0)]$$ and we should be done since $L\sqrt{n}(X_n-x_0)\Rightarrow L(X)$, but how come we can say that $\sqrt{n} [o(X_n - x_0)]$ vanishes?

If we had something like $1/\sqrt{n}$ for $o(X_n-x_0)$, then $\sqrt{n} [o(X_n - x_0)]$ would not vanish. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, it vanishes because of the following theorem:

If $Y_n$ is a sequence of Random Variables which is bounded in probability and if $X_n=o_p (Y_n)$. Then $X_n\to 0$ in probability, as n $\to \infty$.

In your case, the remainder is bounded because $X_n$ converges in distribution to $x_0$ and all sequences convergent in distribution are bounded in probability.

Does that help?

Comment: But if you pick $X_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$, which goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, then $\sqrt{n} X_n = 1$ for all $n$. That doesn't vanish.

Comment: I think the answer above is right. The trick is that while $\sqrt{n} X_n$ does not vanish, it is however bounded, so $o(\sqrt{n}X_n)$ does vanish. To be honest, I'm not sure how to get the root n inside the o function, but I bet you can.

Comment: $X_n = n^{-1/4}$ then. Here $\sqrt{n}X_n$ is not bounded but $X_n$ still converges to $0$.